# Splitting a region of an image into tiles

Tags: imagemagick

I have a set of images that are 4500px x 3000px in size.

Out of each of these images I need to extract a set of tiles in a 5 columns by 3 rows combination with each tile being 700px wide by 500px high.

What complicates the above is that the starting point for this needs to be at X:650 and Y:450 position from the top left corner of the image.

I have gotten as far as `convert image.jpg -gravity NorthWest -chop 650x450 -crop 700x500 tile-%d.jpg`

This gets me to a correct start position for creating the tile set but includes the rest of the blank area in the right and bottom edge of the image.

How do I go about solving this?

[image: Illustration of the problem]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within a single ImageMagick command you can crop the initial rectangle that contains all the tiles first, then crop that into the 15 output images. Try something like this...

```
convert image.jpg -crop 3500x1500+650+450 -crop 5x3@ tile-%02d.jpg
```

Comment: I had it in my mind that I can't use the same option twice. Thanks!